# Why set both the property and the setter as Bindable?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have inherited a large Flex project which uses binding and ChangeWatchers all over the place – it's like some massive pinball machine of background events firing. I really dislike data binding (although I guess I appreciate how it can be useful) so I haven't bothered to learn it in depth.

Why would one have both the property and the setter for the property be bindable?

```
   [Bindable]
    protected var _transformEnabled:Boolean = false;
```

..

```
    [Bindable]
    public function set transformEnabled(value:Boolean):void{
        _transformEnabled = value;
    }
```

Comment: Using [bindable] has to be done in a sporadic way. Using about 10 bindable in one project can start lagging a app on mobile device. Each bindable uses a good amount of CPU and so they must only be used in a strategic way. I've seen before "flex developers" using bindable all over the place for the only purpose of being very lazy and not care about the quality of their work. My advise: change it.

Answer (score 0):

You typically wouldn't unless somewhere in the code it's binding directly to `_transformEnabled`. (e.g. `<SomeComponent isTransformed={_transformEnabled} />`)

Comment: Agreed, was going to say this. Since it's a write-only property the storage var has to be used to read and bind. What I don't know is why you would say `[Bindable]` on the setter for a write-only property, does that even do anything useful? I don't think it does.